# Does gcloud storage python client API support parallel composite upload?

Tags: python, gcloud, gsutil, google-python-api

The `gsutil` command has options to optimize upload/download speed for large files. For example

```
GSUtil:parallel_composite_upload_threshold=150M
GSUtil:sliced_object_download_max_components=8
```

see [this page](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/optimizing-your-cloud-storage-performance-google-cloud-performance-atlas) for reference.

What is the equivalence in the `google.cloud.storage` python API? I didn't find the relevant parameters in [this document](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/storage/blobs.html).

In general, does the client API and `gsutil` have one to one correspondence in terms of functionalities?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's not natively supported.

However (!) if you're willing to decompose files then use `threading` or `multiprocessing`, there is a [`compose`](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/blobs.html#google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob.compose) method that should help you assemble the parts into one GCS object.

Ironically, `gsutil` is written in Python but it uses a library [`gslib`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/tree/0e629ab55032b799ec728c05a71faf72cd49ff48/gslib) to implement parallel uploads. You may be able to use `gslib` as a template.

Comment: Here's an [open issue](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/issues/36) to support parallel operations for copying objects.

Comment: @DonnaldCucharo the issue you linked to is for copying objects in parallel, while composite upload is about chunking large files to speed up the operations using composite objects (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/composite-objects).

Comment: I opened an issue to add support for parallel composite upload: https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/issues/1202

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `transfer_manager` module of the [Python Client for Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest) or in this [sample code](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/multipart-uploads#storage-upload-object-chunks-python). It has methods for file up/download where you pass it the object to copy, set the chunk size and number of workers, and the module takes care of the rest.

It uses the Multipart XML API which allows even higher parallelization than `gcloud storage` of `gsutil`, and avoids potential bucket feature interop issues too. I wrote about this and more in my recent blog post ["High throughput file transfers with Google Cloud Storage (GCS)](https://www.beginswithdata.com/2024/02/01/google-cloud-storage-max-throughput/).