# How do I Parallelize a Databricks File Copy/Upload Operation?

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

I'm running Databricks on Microsoft Azure.  I am copying all files from a Databricks dbfs path to a GCP/GCS bucket (Google Cloud Platform / Google Cloud Storage bucket) by using the python libraries named google-cloud-storage and google-cloud-core.  I installed these libraries with PyPl and I'm using the 'upload_from_filename' command from the google-cloud-storage python library.  The source directory contains hundreds of files and the total volume of files is more than 100 GB.  The file copy/upload is successful, but the copy/upload operation occurs one-by-one, one file at a time.

My question is: how can I force Databricks to 'Parallelize' the copy/upload operation (i.e. perform the copy operation in multiple threads asynchronously)?

The following is my code (gcp bucket name and source file paths are modified for clarity)

```
from google.cloud import storage
from datetime import datetime

storage_client = storage.Client()
bucket = storage_client.bucket('the-gcp-bucket')
files = dbutils.fs.ls('dbfs:/sourcefilepath/')
filenumber = 0

for fi in files:
  source_file_name = fi.path
  source_file_name = source_file_name.replace("dbfs:", "/dbfs")
  blob = bucket.blob('TargetSubFolder/' + fi.name)
  blob.upload_from_filename(source_file_name)
  filenumber = filenumber + 1
  print("File num: {} {} uploaded to {}.".format(str(filenumber), source_file_name, destination_blob_name))
  
print("File Copy Complete")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does gcloud storage python client API support parallel composite upload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55249311/does-gcloud-storage-python-client-api-support-parallel-composite-upload)

Comment: This is also an open issue on GitHub: https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/issues/36